# How do I fix my color for the original Diablo?

Tags: diablo

I'm going back with some friends to play through the original Diablo and it has been looking really oddly colored. It either has full on technicolor:

[image: Screenshot of Diablo with the regular colors replaced with garish alternates]

Or just random color particles on the edges of objects. Does anyone know of a way to fix this bug? I'm trying to run it on a 64 bit Windows 7 machine.

Comment: [There's nothing wrong with your computer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Outer_Limits_(1963_TV_series)#Introduction)

Comment: At first I was like "wuh.." then I lol'd.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Crazy as this sounds, you can kill explorer.exe from the task manager once you have Diablo open, and it will fix your technicolor issues.  This seems to work with a lot of other older games in Win 7 64-bit.

Comment: you also might try running it in XP compatibility mode, running it in 256 colors, disabling visual themes and/or disabling desktop composition; all through the Compatibility tab of the file/shortcut properties.

Comment: I actually tried to do XP compatibility mode, but it only worked for about five minutes. When I hit a load screen it technicolored again. So far killing explorer has worked though.

Comment: I know this is vague, but iirc the Blizzard website has a registry hack that redoes the color to make it compatible. However, my friend's computer had some display issues afterward, so do it only as a last solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
Try this solution from [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/gaming/25654-diablo-weird-colour-fix.html)

1. Install the game. (if already installed please backup your saved games, uninstall the game, delete the files remaining in the folder that was installed and install the game again)
2. Download the update 1.09 from [Blizzard Support](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-patch-information;jsessionid=FBAD457B597AB687A828557C96296E7A.blade35_08_bnet-support).
3. Once downloaded run the update as administrator. (remember that the game disc must be in the drive)
4. Download this file [DiabloFIX.zip](http://www.filedropper.com/diablofix).
5. Extract and copy the file to the game folder.
6. Edit your game shortcut 
   In Games Explorer: First open Games Explorer and wait until the game update the stats, now close and go to C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\GameExplorer sort the folders by date and it should be the one down the GamesBoxArt folder, open the folder {#-#-#-#-#}>PlayTasks>0 right-click in the game icon and go to properties, replace the .exe for .bat at the end of the target path
   or
   In Start Menu: Go to All Programs>Diablo> right-click in the game icon and go to properties, replace the .exe for .bat at the end of the target path
7. Make sure that the game is not setting to run in compatibility mode or disabling settings.

My original answer was for Diablo 2. My mistake. Sorry.
<strike>**Edit**
Also I had to disable desktop composition and run the game in Windows XP compatibility mode. HTH.</strike>

This happened to me and my solution was to use the 3Dfx Glide Library on Windows 7. [This](http://www.zeus-software.com/downloads/nglide) link was able to help me solve my issues.

Answer (score -1):

Also, you can use the same fix used to correct Age of Empires II. Make a new text document on the desktop (right click New text Document)
Copy+paste the following into the document:

taskkill /F /IM Explorer.exe
DIABLO.EXE
Start explorer.exe

SAVE AS whatever you want - just change it to save as all files on the save as tab and end your file name with .bat (ex diablofix.bat). Move this file into the diablo path folder. Then create a shortcut for the file on  the desktop. You should be good to go!. (As extra ammo I downloaded a registry fix and run it while on Windows 7 basic (you can change to this by right clicking on desktop - personalize - windows 7 basic is at bottom).
REG fix - http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/rainbow-or-washed-out-colors-windows-7

CHEERS

Comment: Killing explorer to play a game is *extremely* bad practice.  I don't think we should be advocating anyone do this.